# Changing wifi username

Tags: networking, wireless

My pupils are supposed to log on to the school wifi using individual usernames/passwords. Is there any way of not storing the usernames of previous users? Currently they have to edit connections, remove the network, reenter all the information, and click the annoying prompts. I think this question is similar:

[WiFi temporary username settings with PEAP/MSCHAPv2 on 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/555414/wifi-temporary-username-settings-with-peap-mschapv2-on-14-04)

It's still unanswered. Please help.
Im using Lubuntu 14.10

Comment: Would it work to remove _all_ prior connection informations each time the system is booted?

Comment: It would help somewhat. How do I do that?

Comment: **@Andreas :** And if needed, you can do the same thing on log-on as well.  If you need that as well, leave a comment @Fabby

Comment: That would be even better. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

This procedure will eliminate *all* prior connections in Network Manager on system boot. Please open a terminal and do:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Right above `exit 0` add the following lines:

```
rm  /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*
service network-manager restart
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor. All prior connections, passwords, access points, etc. will have been deleted.